# Parse Server Field ACL

Tags: security, parse-platform

It is possible to define Field ACL or Field Group Access with parse server ?

For example, i have this object:
{
   name: "toto",
   validation: false
}

I want only admin user can be set the value of `validation` fields.

Comment: have u read the docs ? sample from REST guide : http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#access-control-lists

Comment: @RobertRowntree yes, i read it. is not the same. ACL concerns only one object, but not field of this object.

Comment: then use a pointer to the validation in the parent object and enforce ACL in a separate, 'validation' object with its own ACL

Comment: ok, i see. i will try it.